# How to obtain picture metadata using perl, php

Tags: php, linux, perl, image-processing, metadata

How do I obtain the metadata for a png or jpg image?  I have a few thousand images that get processed by a perl script.  One of the things that I need to be able to get from each image is the metadata for them.

The most important information is the date listed in bold.  I would like to have a script I can run that will grab the date info from each of the pictures that I process.  It would be ideal if it is in perl, but php would work too.  this is running on a Linux system.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you

Here is an example of one of the images:
[image]

Here is the metadata for this image:

**Sep 30, 2010**

849×571 pixels – 825KB

Filename: EA_A02_N_1-4_5mM_Xgal_7d_B.cropped.resized.grey.png

Camera: Canon

Model: Canon EOS DIGITAL REBEL XSi

ISO: 200

Exposure: 1/50 sec

Aperture: 2.8

Focal Length: 60mm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664/what-is-the-best-a-very-good-meta-data-reader-library

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708417/how-can-i-extract-exif-data-using-perlmagick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [ExifTool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)

Answer (score 2):

In php you can use [exif_read_data()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) function .

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/photos/),
it's good application that was used in Typo3 to retrieve image's MetaData.
when you want to execute it, you can use the **exec()** or **system()** functions

Comment: There are also Perl bindings for it.  Not sure about PHP.